# How to pass the path of any SQL file from excel to execute it on talend

Tags: talend

I need to execute the SQL files in talend but want to run those in sequence like providing the path for each file through excel sheet and than pass the path of that excel in talend and the talend will read the excel file and load each file one by one into the database.

I tried tfileList component but on that we need to provide the path for any particular folder and that will load those files which exists on that irrespective of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you want to execute those sql files but if you want to get the path from the excel file you can just read the excel file and then path the flow to a tFlowToIterate component to read the sql files and retrieve the query into a globalVar and use it in tDBRow component.

So it would give something like this :

[image]

And for the tFileInputExcel you need to configure it so that it reads the column containing the path to your sql files :

[image]

Then use a tFlowToIterate to read the paths from the excel and store it in a globalVar :

[image]

Then use a tFileInputRaw to read the sql file (with the globalVar you configured in the tFlowToIterate) :

[image]

Then store the query in another globalvar :

[image]

Which is then used in a tDBRow component :

[image]